# sed find lines with sequential numbers and copy them sorted to new file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to get some file content sorted.
The file content looks like

```
...
description of file
http://linktofile/33.txt
description of file
http://linktofile/11.txt
description of file
http://linktofile/22.doc
...
```

Now I want to cut the entries out and paste them into a new file in correct order so it looks like

```
description of file
http://linktofile/11.txt
description of file
http://linktofile/22.doc
description of file
http://linktofile/33.txt
...
```

Is it possible to let sed look for the number in that lines with link and then cut the whole line out into a new file with correct order and also with the respective above file description?

Comment: `sed` is not the right tool for the job

Comment: You should use different descriptions in the example to show they must be sorted with the links. A custom sort_by is somewhat awkward in basic shell tools, do you have `jq` available? e.g. `jq -R -n -rs '[inputs | capture("(?<link>.*\nhttp.*/(?<num>\\d+).*)"; "g")] | sort_by(.num | tonumber)[].link'`

Comment: isnt jq a tool for json content? I dont know it honestly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok guys thx for your thoughts.
I found solution on my own and want to share it with you. Its maybe more like a workaround and fiddly but in the end does what I want.

Step 1: Delete all newlines and replace them with some indicator so every 2 lines become 1 line

```
sed -i 'N;s/\n/ ## /' file
```

Step 2: On recurring part in every link insert an indicator for sort

```
sed -i 's/recurringpart\//recurringpart\/~/g' file
```

Step 3: Use sort to tidy up the mess.

```
sort -t~ -k2 -g -r -o file file
```

Step 4 : Replace the "newline indicator" with newline so every line gets separated in 2 lines again

```
sed -i 's/ ## /\n/g' file
```

Step 5: Remove the sort indicator

```
sed -i 's/recurringpart\/~/recurringpart\//g' file
```

Comment: There is no "recurringpart" in your question so I don't know what you're using that for and other answers show you more robust (yours would fail if the input contained `<blank>##<blank>` or `~` and would trash your input file if a failure ocurred), efficient (you're calling 5 tools and updating the input file 5 times vs 3 tools and updating it once), and portable (you're relying on GNU sed) ways to implement the decorate/sort/undecorate idiom.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no tabs in your input, you could do it like this:

```
<infile paste - - | sort -t $'\t' -k2,2V | tr '\t' '\n'
```

Output:

```
description of file
http://linktofile/11.txt
description of file
http://linktofile/22.doc
description of file
http://linktofile/33.txt
```

Comment: tried that code but seems tricky. replaced <infile with input file but bash wants permissions. after set to 755 it works but with error message  folder or file not found and output to new file is empty. also from screen output i could see the sorting is not like i need it.

Comment: Please be more specific about what went wrong, and perhaps edit your original post to show examples.

Comment: @diggidre - the principle applied here is basically a type of [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). You might need to vary the [`sort`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) keys and/or use pure numeric sorting instead of "version" sort, but for the information provided it's a good solution.

Comment: @diggidre: sounds like you forgot the redirection character (`<`), without it `bash` tries to execute `infile`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the idiomatic decorate-sort-undecorate:

```
$ awk -F'[/.]' -v OFS='\t' 'NR%2{desc=$0; next} {print $(NF-1), NR-1, desc ORS $(NF-1), NR, $0}' file |
    sort -k1,2n | cut -f3-
description of file
http://linktofile/11.txt
description of file
http://linktofile/22.doc
description of file
http://linktofile/33.txt
```